# Repeat records based on date - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algorithm, activerecord

I have a table of events that have start and end dates.

Now I want to fetch events for particular dates. i.e if I supply 1 May 2014, 2 May 2004, I need all events happening on that day (based on start and end dates). And I need to group the events based on the start date and display them as a list.

Now problem is if an event takes place on two days, say 1 May and 2 May, I need to display the event twice in the list like so:

```
1 May 2014
EventName

2 May 2014
EventName
```

I am not sure how to do this... Can anyone help me come up with an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Actually I don't have ruby, Can you try thsi code `start_date = some_date
end_date = other_date
events = Event.where(:start_date => [start_date, end_date]).where(:end_date => [start_date, end_date])
events.each do |event|
  puts "#{event.date}"
  puts "#{event.name}"
end
`                        hope it helps

Comment: To print it in sorted order, before looping `events.sort_by! {|event| event.start_date}`, it will sort events based on start_date

Comment: I believe you want to iterate the days between start and end date and for each day, display the events where that day falls between start and end date of that event. I'm at my cellphone now, but you can query all events that falls between start and end date and then iterate on the days between start and end date. Inside that block you would use select on the query to get what events are happening that day.

Comment: Try to fetch and display all events on each day.i.e iterate data not on the basis on event rather iterate on the basis of event dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
events = Event.where("start_date >= ? AND end_date <= ?", start_date, end_date)

display_events = Hash.new

(start_date..end_date).each do |date|
    display_events[date] << events.select { |event| event.start_date <= date and event.end_date >= date }
end
```

Here you end up having a hash with events grouped by date. (I'm on cellphone, so I couldn't test it)

Comment: Thanks man!! I never thought of it in this way :) Now it makes lots of sense!!

Answer (score 2):

To get the events to appear twice I would add separately created collections together.

```
events = []
(start_date..end_date).each do |date|
  events += Event.where("start_date >= ? and end_date <= ?", date, date)
end
events
```

Comment: Would that be more efficient then querying the events that falls between start and end date just once, and then using select to get the events for each day?

Answer (score 0):

Try to fetch and display all events on each day.i.e iterate data not on the basis on event rather iterate on the basis of event dates.

```
s_date = Date.parse('2010-09-29')
e_date = Date.parse('2010-09-30')

sd.upto(ed) do |date|
  @events = Event.event_on_date(date) 
end
```

Comment: Thanks Nitin. It makes sense when I think interms of the dates! :) Thanks